# Remove bullet points from HTML list items

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the bullet points from `#box5`, `#box6` and `#box7`? I thought it would be by using `#box5 a`, but it's not working.

### HTML

```
<div id="con3">
    <!-- irrelevant markup omitted -->

    <div id="box5">
        <li><a href="#">LIAM PRICE<br>Australia</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="box6">
        <li><a href="#">JESS KWARTZ<br>Germany</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="box7">
        <li><a href="#">ALI JAB<br>Mexico</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#box5 {
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    font-family: 'pt_serifitalic';
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 16px;  
}

#box5 a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;   
}
```

Comment: Before that you don't have a code standerd,  you should use li inside the ul or ol, and the multiple li does not need multiple parent elements please change your code first

Comment: There is no reason to use li here, they should be within an ol or ul anyway.

Comment: @lily, if none of the answers worked or your still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 6):

You need to put `list-style:none` on a parent container like

```
#box5, #box6, #box7{
  list-style: none;
  }
```

or apply to the `li` elements directly

```
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Also, **surround** your `li` elements with a `ul` element

```css
#con3 {
 width:1024px;
 height:680px;
 background-color: #161717;
 background-image: url(media/blogs5.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 55px;
 float:none;
 text-decoration:none;

 }

#box4 { 
float:none;
width:300px;
height:195px;
margin-left:580px;
padding-top:60px;
}

#box5 {
margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: 10px; 
font-family: 'pt_serifitalic';
font-size: 9pt;
line-height: 16px;  
}


#box5 a {
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}

#box5, #box6, #box7{
  list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="con3">
<div id="box4">
<span class="fontheading">SHARE, INSPIRE <br>AND CONNECT </span><br><hr class="white"><br>
<span class="font1">You&#39;ll follow your<br> friends and make <br>new ones   as you discover 
the world through the<br>Amalfi travellor.</span>
<br><br><span class="font2">Read and post blogs,<br> ask questions <br>and      recieve answers </span>
</div>

<ul id="box5">
<li><a href="#">LIAM PRICE<br>Australia</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="box6">
<li><a href="#">JESS KWARTZ<br>Germany</a></li>
</ul>


<ul id="box7">
<li><a href="#">ALI JAB<br>Mexico</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put list items `LI` in either a `UL` or `OL` or `menu` to follow the HTML spec. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Bullets are on all the `LI`s in the `UL`s or `OL`s, so we can fix it with:

```
UL {list-style: none}
```

Because of inheritance, this style will be transferred to the 'list-style' of the LI elements.

See also the [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp) examples.

Answer (score 1):

Bullets are on `LI`s, so:

```
li {list-style: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the list item class to: `list-style:none`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the bullet points of  #box5, #box6 and #box7

then use this

```
#box5, #box6, #box7 {

        list-style:none;
    }
```

But you should use `li` tag inside `ul` to be syntactically correct
and then use the following code

```
ul li {

            list-style:none;
        }
```